# How to make wordwrap consider a whitespace in a string as a regular character?

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, whitespace, word-wrap

I want to create a multiline textbox control that will be used for an application as "Snap to grid" when all of the characters are Monospaced, and the fitting font size was found (for example - for a textbox with 6 columns, exactly 6 characters should be entered). - Of course with Word Wrap!

As for the above - it's OK. The correct way to calculate the font size was found.

The only issue is that I need to create an "Alt+Enter" option to represent "Enter".

For some reasons, I can't use \r\n and need that all of the remaining line space will be full of whitespaces.
The thing is that wrap doesn't accept spaces in an amount which is larger than the textbox's width.
For example:

If I write in a textbox with width=8cells, the following (or paste that string etc..):

"Hello      World!" ("Hello+6Whitespaces+World!")

I would like to recieve: (_=whitespace)

First Line: Hello___

Second Line: ___World

Third Line: !

What really happens is:

First Line: Hello___

Second Line: World!

(No spaces at all in the beginning of the second line)

PS - On debug I can see that the spaces (all of them) are considered as a part of the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, try `Environment.NewLine` instead of `\r\n`. That will ensure you get the correct line breaks on your target platform.

Secondly, Word Wrap is likely ignoring extra spaces, so you need to replace normal spaces with a unicode non-breaking space. The unicode character for that is `\u00A0`.

You need to replace all normal spaces with the unicode non-breaking space:

```
string spaceReplacer = "\u00A0";
```

And to use it, try this:

```
textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text.Replace(" ", spaceReplacer);
```

Or even this:

```
textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text.Replace(" ", "\u00A0");
```

Comment: Thanks SecuriTree!! It worked...! (I mustn't use any NewLine option, so the solution for the spaces works like a charm!)

Comment: One more question... For some reason, this replacement to "\u00A0" raises TextChanged 5 times (apparently according to the letters amount...). Do you have any idea of how to solve this?

Comment: Thanks for the update.. I tried this before but it wasn't it. I think that maybe the problem is that this text from the textbox is being synced with some other text area, and when checking there if the string was changed, comparing one with " " and one with "\u00A0" aren't equals.. Do you have any solution for that? Thanks!!!!