# How to move the cursor in multiline textbox from the end of the line to the beginning of the next one?

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, cursor, word-wrap

I have a multiline textbox with wordwrap on, while I want it's cursor to be located in the beginning of the next line when it arrives at the end of the current one.

e.g. - if 8 characters can be entered in line (monospaced), and I enter this:

12345678

I would like the cursor to be under the '1' char (and not after the 8).

The challenge is: I can't use NewLine as a part of the textbox string.

Answer (score 0):

You could subscribe for notifications when the textbox changes, and if there's 8 characters add an Environment.NewLine to the text. After the first line you'd have to do a split on the text to only get the last line but that's not too hard. The user will always be able to manually move the cursor to the end of the line again though so you'd need to add logic to check if there are 9 characters on the line and delete the last one.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help! I can't use NewLine as a part of the string. I've edited the question... :(

Comment: Why can't you use NewLine?

Comment: What about using NewLine and just remove them when reading it out again?

Comment: @CallumBradbury -  I can't use NewLine because I implement a textbox which is snapped to some grid and I need any empty cell to be considered as space...

Comment: @jannik - I tried to add NewLine and remove - the cursor returns that way to its wrong location (end of line)...

Comment: Your reasoning for not using NewLine is pretty vague, maybe update the OP with a bit more detail about your requirements. I'm fairly sure it isn't going to be possible without NewLine though, as that's what you use to move the cursor to a new line.

Comment: @CallumBradbury - Sorry... this is the requirement :( I can't use NewLine but believe there's another solution. PS - When I added extra space and setted the cursor to one position before - it worked, but I don't want the redundant space... Thanks anyway!!

Answer (score 0):

The thing that finally solved my problem, while taking into account the limitation of NOT using Environment.NewLine was adding one more additional space, save the SelectionStart position, and calculate the correct one without considering the redundant space (see another post about [How to make wordwrap consider a whitespace in a string as a regular character?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32888556/how-to-make-wordwrap-consider-a-whitespace-in-a-string-as-a-regular-character))

This solution fits for a very special case in which I've created my own "NewLine" for our use which will occur while the user will click Alt+Enter - The amount of relevant spaces will be added to fill a line (then I needed the cursor to go down... this was the issue!):

```
private void TextBox_OnPreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        var tb = sender as TextBox;

        if (Keyboard.Modifiers == ModifierKeys.Alt && Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.Enter))
        {
            int origSelectionStart = tb.SelectionStart;

            int paddingSpacesAmountToAdd = WidthInCells - (tb.Text.Substring(0, tb.SelectionStart)).Length%WidthInCells;
            int origPaddingSpacesAmountToAdd = paddingSpacesAmountToAdd;

            // Only if the cursor is in the end of the string - add one extra space that will be removed eventually.
            if (tb.SelectionStart == tb.Text.Length) paddingSpacesAmountToAdd++;

            string newText = tb.Text.Substring(0, tb.SelectionStart) + new String(' ', paddingSpacesAmountToAdd) + tb.Text.Substring(tb.SelectionStart + tb.SelectionLength);
            tb.Text = newText;

            int newSelectionPos = origSelectionStart + origPaddingSpacesAmountToAdd;
            tb.SelectionStart = newSelectionPos;

            e.Handled = true;
        }
        else if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.Enter))
        {
            //source already updated because of the binding UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```

That won't be enough (as I mentioned above - there's a spaces issue), so:

```
void _textBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        int origCursorLocation = _textBox.SelectionStart;
        // Regular Whitespace can't be wrapped as a regular character, thus - we'll replace it. 
        _textBox.Text.Replace(" ", "\u00A0");
        _textBox.SelectionStart = origCursorLocation;
    }
```

**Important** - This solution works for MonoSpace characters when there's a calculation of the exact fitting fontsize.